# Swift file upload

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsurlsession

I've followed Apple documentation based on what an `uploadTaskWithRequest` requires as arguments to upload a file. It all seems very straight forward to me but I am only seeing the request hitting the server and nothing else gets uploaded. I am using PHP and the `$_FILES` and `$_POST` arrays are always empty on the server side (running on the Apache+PHP comes shipped with OSX). The `session` variable is defined and initiated somewhere else.

```
  let url = "http://localhost/upload.php"
  let file = "image.png"
  uploadFile(url,file)

  func uploadFile(url: String, file: String) {
    let filePath = mediaDir?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(file)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    println(filePath,url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let task = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request,
        fromFile: filePath!)

    task.resume()
  }
```

What I am doing wrong here? Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is your image.png located?

Comment: on a `media` folder under the `Documents` inside the user's home.

Comment: i have updated the answer showing how to create an url for your local resource file.

Comment: Not sure what's with the downvotes party!

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with PHP much anymore, so perhaps it has changed.  In the case of your upload `let task = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request,fromFile: filePath!)`
does not create a multipart/form POST, but instead a post whose Content-Type is application/octet-stream, and contents are the raw file itself.  In other words, you won't get the file in $_POST or $_FILES.

I think you can get the file like:

```
$upload = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Might be outdated, but it might be a good place to start.